# Is there a way to avoid browser repainting when using js function document.appendchild?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I read that document.appendchild() was a good way to move DOM's elements because it keep them in memory, but checking the browser, i noticed that the moved elements are repainting. Is there a way to avoid this? Maybe not using appendChild but another function that allow move elements without repainting them?

The best solution i've found is using transform: translate, but this is not exactly what i'm looking for, this just move the element around on the screen, it does not change it position in the DOM.

Comment: I don't understand how it could make sense to move an element and *not* repaint. If you don't want the fact that it has moved to be visible, why are you moving it?

Comment: Is your goal to minimize the repaint or to complete do without repainting?

Unless your elements have no user interface there will be some degree of repainting.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, but @nnnnnn is right that moving an element is in itself a repaint.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best approach to repainting is not to do away with it, but to handle it with grace.

The ultimate goal is to limit changes to the DOM as much as possible, which it seems would be your goal.

In terms of moving an element, it certainly depends upon your element, but you would want to ensure a few things about how you add the element.

1. Establish a destination for the element that won't require a page reflow. If you can do this before you move the element, you will be in better shape.
2. Ensure that the actual changes to the DOM are contained, and animations are done in bulk via CSS whenever possible. Sounds like you are handling this through translate, which is lower-impact since it doesn't change the DOM.
3. To accomplish your goal of actually moving the element to a new place in the DOM, after you translate an element to its new location, you should be able to append a copy of it to the new location and then remove the old translated element without requiring any pixel of the page to be changed.

Ultimately, this will not do away with a page repaint, but you should be able to largely eliminate page reflows, and in the process greatly reduce repainting.

Answer (score 0):

Just off my mind, in case it helps. Setting the below CSS property to elements might avoid repainting of the whole DOM

```
.element {
    will-change: transform;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```